: Firebase Cloud Firestore Security Rules Preventing Data Access
I'm currently facing an issue with my Firebase Cloud Firestore setup. I have a project called "OrderFood," and I’m trying to read data from my Firestore database. However, I keep receiving an error message stating that my bucket "chatai-new11.appspot.com" is denying client requests due to the current security rules.
Here are my current Firestore security rules:


I attempted to change the rules to allow read and write access, but I’m unsure how to do this securely.
I also checked the Firebase documentation, but I still need clarification on how to set appropriate rules that balance security with functionality.
Could someone please guide me on how to update my Firestore security rules to allow for proper data access while ensuring the security of my application?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Error comes from firebase storage not from firestore, the rules you've added only applicable for firestore, you need to add rules for storage , something like
https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#default_rules_locked_mode
I would recommend even for read, only allow authenticated entities

Please don't screenshots of code or other textual content, but rather post them as actual text and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark them up. Having the content as text makes it accessible, searchable and makes it easier for folks to help you. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?
